# Selenium not detect more than one windows

Tags: java, selenium

I have a script that runs on different machines, but I have a problem in one of the VMs that does not detect more than one screen.

[This is the script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZnHZ.jpg)

Comment: Any `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions` will throw `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException` if the expectation is already met.

Comment: Throw the exception because driver.getWindowHandles().size() = 1

Comment: Please prefer copy/paste than show code as image